# Turning a list into an indexed array

Tags: java, regex, arrays, object

I have a list of values in a text file,

```
 People.txt[
 Name, ID, DOB, Sex
 Bill, 12, 12/12/1989, Male
 Cindy, 13, 12/11/1991, Female
 ]
```

I had originally read the values into a string then transformed the string into an array at the ',' value using

```
 List<String> items = Arrays.asList(str.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
```

but I want to try and find a way to either create an object containing the headings and sort them into lists or an array of associative arrays with indexes for all of the values.

I'm fairly rookie at Java and I can't figure out how to transform the values into an array with headings.

Comment: Where is your data coming from? Is it a CSV? Because there's some open source CSV readers out there.

Comment: No, it's just a .txt file I could transform it to CSV then read it but I was hoping for a quicker/dirtier way to do it.
Can you recommend an open source reader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 String[] lines = str.split("\n");
 String[] header = lines[0].split("\\s?,\\s?");

 List< String[] > data = new ArrayList< String[] >();
 for ( int i=1; i<lines.length; i++ ) {
     data.add( lines[i].split("\\s?,\\s?") );
 }
```

haven't run the code ... but should be enough to get the idea :)

you'll need to index `data` the same way as you index `header` since that is what you seemed to ask for e.g. you can wrap this in an object of your own :

```
class PeopleData implements Iterable<String[]> {

    final String[] headers;
    final List< String[] > data;

    public PeopleData(final String str) {
        String[] lines = str.split("\n");
        this.headers = lines[0].split("\\s?,\\s?");

        data = new ArrayList<String[] >();
        for ( int i=1; i<lines.length; i++ ) {
            data.add( lines[i].split("\\s?,\\s?") );
        }
    }

    public int size() {
        return headers.length;
    }

    public String[] getHeaders(int i) {
        return headers;
    }

    public String getHeader(int i) {
        return headers[i];
    }

    public String[] getRow(int i) {
        return data.get(i);
    }

    public String getData(int header, int i) {
        final String[] row = getRow(i);
        return row[header];
    }

    public String getData(String header, int i) {
        final int index = index(header);
        if ( index == -1 ) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("header '" + header + "' not found");
        }
        return getData(index, i);
    }

    private int index(final String header) {
        for ( int i=0; i< headers.length; i++ ) {
            if ( header.equals( headers[i] ) ) return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<String[]> iterator() {
        return data.iterator();
    }

}
```

Comment: Where does the 'append' method come from?

Comment: @a_programmer should have been `add` sorry

Answer (score 2):

The data structure you'll need to hold this associative array (Map) is:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map;
```

1. When you split first record you can store it in a `List<String>` called `headers`
2. When you split next records then insert into this map using:

   ```
   String[] vals = str.split("\\s*,\\s*");
   for (int i=0; i<vals.length; i++) {
       List<String> cols = map.get(headers.get(i));
       if (cols == null) cols = new ArrayList<String>();
       cols.add(vals[i]);
       map.put(headers.get(i), cols);
   }
   ```

Comment: Actually it needed index value to fetch header string.

Comment: is headers part of Map or do I need to create them too?

Comment: Every key in map is like `Name` OR `ID` OR  `DOB` so no need to store `headers` separately.